# Can you prove this..?

Tags: group-theory

If $H$ is a normal subgroup of a group $G$ and $g^{2}\in H$ for all $g\in G$ then $[G:H]\leq 2$.

I have no idea about this.

As we know $H\unlhd G$ $\frac{|G|}{|H|}=2$. We can claim the result and show that it is true.

Thanks..

Comment: Actually, its converse is true. if $[G:H]=2$ then $g^2\in H$.

Comment: could you put a more informative title, please?

Answer (score 5):

The smallest counterexample is to take $G$ to be the (unique up to isomorphism) non-cyclic group of order 4 and take $H$ to consist of just the identity element.

Answer (score 0):

That statement is not true. For $H = id$ and $G =\langle (1 2), (3 4)\rangle$ , abelian group.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Finite case: If $H \lhd G$, with the property that for all $g \in G$,  $g^2 \in H$, this means that for every $\bar g \in G/H -\{\bar 1\}$, order$(\bar g)=2$. It is well-known that then $G/H$ must be abelian and in fact $G/H \cong C_2 \times \dots \times C_2$, a direct product of a certain number of cyclic groups of order $2$. As the examples above show the direct product does not have to consist of only a single factor.